# Python in VSCode: Why can come cell outputs be set to HTML, while others only text?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebooks and Python in VSCode. In the recent update (I don't know the version numbers), they put in the functionality to change the output style. However, some cell output allow me to set it to HTML, while others only text. Why would this be?
And it can't be the contents/code - for example, I have one cell which gives nice HTML output for a describe method:
[image]

While, further down, I have the same, but then I get
[image]

any ideas?
Also any idea as to why the two instances of the same method is not giving the same results?

Comment: Jupyter Notebook is a notebook kind of environment. So to keep it neat, you could use the `HTML` options etc...

Comment: like this?  from IPython.display import display, HTML   >> coz this doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your 2nd cell doesn't call the function `describe`, it simply accesses it.

However, if you ever run into an issue with displaying, for instance, `pandas` as raw text instead of an HTML table, you probably want to look into `IPython`'s `display` module.

You can import it like so:

```py
from IPython.display import display
```

---

`display` is actually run under-the-hood on your last line of code. This is why writing:

```py
df
```

will show you a `pd.DataFrame` as a table, whereas that won't happen in a program or regular Python console.

---

There are also a host of other tools in `IPython.display`, like `Markdown`, `HTML`, and `Image`, to name a few.

Comment: Nope, sorry, that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Just checking – once you imported the function, you then called it as you would any function, right? (Assuming it's imported....) You would then do: `display(model_data.describe())`.

Comment: Yup: ``` from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(model_data2.describe) ```
Does nothing.

Comment: `.describe` is a function. You need to specify the `()` to call the function. Otherwise, as I mentioned in my solution, you're simply accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `describe()` and `describe` are different. Use function `type()`, you can see `describe()` is `pandas.core.series.Series`, while `describe` is `method`:

[image]

So the data they show is different too.